# Implementing search : Identifying known keywords

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have implemented search functionality for my e-Commerce website using elastic search. The basic structure is like, each product has a title and whatever the user enters I search the exact string using elastic and return the result.

Now I notice that most of the search phrases (almost 90%) follow a similar pattern. It contains:

1. Brand name of the product (Apple, Nokia etc.)
2. Category of the product (phone, mobile phone, smartphone etc.)
3. Model name of the product (iPhone 6S, Lumia 950 etc.)

Now I think if I am able to identify the specific components, then I can return better results than just text match.

I have list of brands, categories and models. If i am able to identify the terms present, then I can request elasticsearch with that field specifically
For example, a search string of "Apple iPhone 5S", I should be able to deduce that brand=Apple.

**EDIT**: More details as asked in comments

*Structure of document:*

I have a single index and each document ID is the SKU of the product and it contains the following fields

1. title (Apple iPhone 5S)
2. brand (Apple)
3. categ (Electronics)
4. sub_categ (Smartphones)
5. model (iPhone 5S)
6. attribs (dictionary of product attributes particular to each sub_categ like {"color": "gold", "memory": "32 GB", "battery": "1570 mAh"})
7. price

*Use Case:*

Now when the user searches for phrase "iphone 5s battery", elastic returns search results which returns even the phone. (I agree the relevance score matches better for battery)

What I am trying to achieve is, I have master list of sub categories. So if any word from the search phrase is present in the master list, then i would search on elasticsearch with query ["must": {"sub_categ": "battery"}]. So the result from "Smartphones" sub category would not be fetched from elastic. I wish to replicate this across multiple fields like brand, category etc

My question is, how do I find if brand or any other particular word from the master list if present in the search phrase quickly? The only option i could think of is, looping through the master list and check if the word is present in the search phrase. If present, then keep note of it and do the same across all master list field (brand, categ, sub categ). Then generate the query with must and then querying them. I wish to know if there is a better way of accomplishing it.

Comment: can you share your mappings? also what kind of results(documents) would you like to return for query "Apple iPhone 5S"?

Comment: What's your question? You can tokenize your string, and refer to a brand/category/model index. But how does that gain you anything over a keywork oriented search?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 edited the question with more details

Comment: @Sobrique edited the question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person in the Lucene world who has spoken the most on this topic is Ted Sullivan.  (He calls this "auto-filtering", and has [a component which does this available for Solr](https://github.com/LucidWorks/simple-category-extraction-component/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lucidworks/solr/query))

I realize you're using Elasticsearch, but Ted's component works by introspecting FieldCache data (exposed by Lucene) so should be possible to implement something very similar with Elasticsearch (look at the code).

There is also a discussion in [this article](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-query-autofiltering/) about how to create a separate index for providing pre-query intelligence like you've described (e.g. your term "Apple" is most frequently found in the `company` field).

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. But when searching around for query auto filtering for elastic, i do not find anything similar. i hope someone will be able to replicate this in elastic. thanks

Comment: Yes.  It's custom functionality at this point.   If you don't want to program against Lucene, try following the second approach in the article (where you keep a secondary index with "term" and "occurring fields + counts" to pre-query)